# Why does my index.js navbar not showing in app.jsx?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Help!, i can't show my imports (Navbar,Billing,CardDeal,Business,Clients,CTA,Stats,Footer,Tesimonials,Hero) into my App.jsx been doing this for the past hour can someone help me ?

index.js

```
import Navbar from "./Navbar"; 
import Billing from "./Billing"; 
import CardDeal from "./CardDeal"; 
import Business from "./Business"; 
import Clients from "./Clients"; 
import CTA from "./CTA";
import Stats from "./Stats"; 
import Footer from "./Footer"; 
import Testimonials from "./Testimonials"; 
import Hero from "./Hero"; 

export default { Navbar, Billing, CardDeal, Business, Clients, CTA, Stats, Footer, Testimonials, Hero, };
```

Comment: index.js import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Billing from "./Billing";
import CardDeal from "./CardDeal";
import Business from "./Business";
import Clients from "./Clients";
import CTA from "./CTA";
import Stats from "./Stats";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Testimonials from "./Testimonials";
import Hero from "./Hero";

export default {
  Navbar,
  Billing,
  CardDeal,
  Business,
  Clients,
  CTA,
  Stats,
  Footer,
  Testimonials,
  Hero,
};

Comment: Can you check if there is any specific error in your browser console